# Random 500 internal errors on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

1. I have around 10 plugins installed.
2. I use a wordpress theme by sitemile.

The site works fine sometimes, but very often, if I were to go to the login or sign up page, it displays the 500 internal error. I want to set up logs for see to see whats happening but I am not sure how I can do that.

Also, sometimes the homepage of the website loads very funky but if i go to other pages, it may or may not load that page properly.

[image]

Not an internet issue. Cleared cache as well. Interestingly, I see different results in normal and incognitu browsers.

Do these internal errors occur most of the time when you have a lot of plugins? Is there some other source of problem that I can check to make sure everything in my site is alright?

Error screenshot attached.

Homepage of website

[image: internal server error encountered when i try to visit other pages on my website]

Comment: Just an FYI: That error is coming straight from the server, so it's nothing to do with your code, as it doesn't even get that far in the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your webhost, you might already have more details in a log file. Often times with apache it's called "error_log" and it can be found in your root directory or the directory of the file causing the error.

It could be anything from access permissions or a security block. So it's going to be hard for someone to give you an answer on this without more information.

**Things to try:**

- You can try disabling one plugin at a time until it works.
- Look for an error_log (or similar) file
- Double check all of the file permissions, chmod and chown
- Contact your web host and see if they can provide any insight
- *If you ARE the web host (or manage the server yourself) then you can check the apache error logs (if enabled) and/or security logs on the server*
- Double check any errors on the .htaccess file
- A script could be consuming too much resources or taking too long to load, you can narrow it down by process of elimination and then disable/patch the culprit

Comment: I started with uninstalling the plugins. Interestingly, the plugins messing this were all cache cleaning and others which normally help in loading a webpage faster. After removing the plugins, the website is fine.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. I suspect the cache plugin was having a hard time storing the cache files. Could have been a file/folder permission issue or a memory limit issue. If you're looking for server side cache, "W3 Total Cache" is a good one to use, or "WP Super Cache" -- I've had success with either depending on your project.

Comment: Interestingly, these were the plugins that gave me the issue.